# Use max page width using rmdformats?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I'm trying to use the entire page width when rendering an R markdown document using rmdformats::readthedown. First, you can see that it isn't a problem using only html_document as the output (and the style definition below the YAML before the 1st chunk).
[image]

YAML and style:

```
---
title: "Data checks for table T32100359"
author: "Crop Reporting Unit, Statistics Canada"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
    html_document:
      keep_md: true
runtime: shiny
---
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

With rmdformats my figure is cut. In fact the whole page is:
[image]

YAML and style:

```
---
title: "Data checks for table T32100359"
author: "Crop Reporting Unit, Statistics Canada"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
    rmdformats::readthedown:
      keep_md: true
runtime: shiny
---
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Note that I also tried

```
<style>
.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: unset;
}
</style>
```

How can I make sure full page width is used with rmdformats?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact problem!!! This is what I got to work:

````
---
title: "Data checks for table T32100359"
author: "Crop Reporting Unit, Statistics Canada"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
    rmdformats::readthedown:
      keep_md: true
runtime: shiny
--- 

    ```{css, echo = FALSE}
    #content{
        max-width:1920px;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( I can't find rmdformat documentation on this either.